# Normal speed range for chassis fans

Tags: fan

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 lts on my desktop pc and I've installed Xsensors. I can see that my cpu fan is running at 3110 rpm, my chassis fan is 0 rpm and my chassis2 fan is a massive 48214 rpm (sometimes going up to over 51000!)
Surely this is wrong. What sort of speed should I expect?
Thanks very much from a new & baffled linux user

Comment: Open the terminal and run the command: `sudo sensors-detect` Then you will get asked a lot of questions about what hardware you want the program to detect. It is generally safe and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions, unless you know what you're doing. The next time you boot the computer maybe Xsensors will work normally.

Comment: 48214 rpm is clearly a bug, above 10,000 rpm you're talking pretty large amounts of energy to spin something that fast (therefore generating heat), a little plastic fan won't be able to go over say 4,000 without a lot of effort.

Answer (score 1):

These are my current speeds, but bear in mind I'm not doing much.

[image]

[image]

So I have a 2220 RMP and a 1046 RPM. You can double those if I'm doing something. Right now I have 17.7 GB of RAM used, and 1 CPU. I'm running a Virtual Box.

I think your first speed is fine, and the second one is suspicious - I think that is a sensor error. What is the temperature like?

Comment: 51000 is definitely not fine. Probably sensor multiplier is wrong.

Comment: @Pilot6 oh, 51000, missed the last 0.

Comment: Xsensor gives a temp of 36°C for cpu & mb

Comment: @David that's fine, my CPUs get up to 70 degrees, and the computer is happy up to 85 degrees.